# WPF. Messagebox. Как поменять стиль диалогового окна?

Tags: c#, wpf, messagebox

Стандартный стиль не вписывается в мой дизайн, а вся валидация идет через `Messagebox.Show("Сообщение")`. Где изменить стиль? Причем надо функционал изменения, как у обычного окна, так как я сделал прозрачный стиль основных окон и использую стилизированные элементы...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Никак. `MessageBox` — системный, он не стилизуется.

Используйте самописный `MessageBox`, благо там писать не сильно много.

Вот вам пример:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Test.MessageBox"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Message Box" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Name="MessageContainer" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Margin="10"/>
        <StackPanel Name="ButtonContainer" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25"/>
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,0,0"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
public partial class MessageBox : Window
{
    public MessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void AddButtons(MessageBoxButton buttons)
    {
        switch (buttons)
        {
        case MessageBoxButton.OK:
            AddButton("OK", MessageBoxResult.OK);
            break;
        case MessageBoxButton.OKCancel:
            AddButton("OK", MessageBoxResult.OK);
            AddButton("Cancel", MessageBoxResult.Cancel, isCancel: true);
            break;
        case MessageBoxButton.YesNo:
            AddButton("Yes", MessageBoxResult.Yes);
            AddButton("No", MessageBoxResult.No);
            break;
        case MessageBoxButton.YesNoCancel:
            AddButton("Yes", MessageBoxResult.Yes);
            AddButton("No", MessageBoxResult.No);
            AddButton("Cancel", MessageBoxResult.Cancel, isCancel: true);
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown button value", "buttons");
        }
    }

    void AddButton(string text, MessageBoxResult result, bool isCancel = false)
    {
        var button = new Button() { Content = text, IsCancel = isCancel };
        button.Click += (o, args) => { Result = result; DialogResult = true; };
        ButtonContainer.Children.Add(button);
    }

    MessageBoxResult Result = MessageBoxResult.None;

    public static MessageBoxResult Show(string caption, string message,
                                        MessageBoxButton buttons)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageBox() { Title = caption };
        dialog.MessageContainer.Text = message;
        dialog.AddButtons(buttons);
        dialog.ShowDialog();
        return dialog.Result;
    }
}
```

В результате у вас получается нормальное окно, и вы можете стилизовать его, как вам угодно.

[image: управдомы]

---

Вам придётся ещё решить проблемы с локализацией, с изменением размеров окна (не стоит давать пользователю возможность максимизировать окно) и т. п.

Comment: логика понятна, спасибо)

Comment: @Awesome7997: Пожалуйста!