# MessageBox из пользовательского Window

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу сделать свой `MessageBox`, с интерфейсом и оформлением. Особо интересует возвращаемое значение - как сделать что бы при выборе ДА или НЕТ выполнялось определенное действие как :

```
if (MessageBoxResult.Yes == MessageBox.Show("Do you want to open Report?", "Report", MessageBoxButton.YesNo))
```

Как организовать класс `BOX` который заменял бы стандартный `MessageBox`? Я пытаюсь сделать это с помощью `partial class ShowWind : Window` и класса `BOX`. Класс `BOX` создает новый экземпляр `ShowWind` :

```
    internal static MessageBoxResult ShowQuestion(string mess, string header)
    {
        ShowWind window = new ShowWind(mess, header);
        window.Show();
        MessageBoxResult result = window.result;
        return result;
    }
```

Если нужно просто вывести какое то сообщение - все нормально а если диалог, где есть выбор `ДА` или `НЕТ` то  `MessageBoxResult` не возвращается. Как должно быть правильно ?

Comment: Если уж решили отказаться от WinForms, зачем типы их тянете? Напишите свой для возвращаемого значения

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620997/wpf-messagebox-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `System.Windows.Window` есть свойство [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.window.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx). Вызываете свою форму через `ShowDialog()` а в самой форме присваиваете данному свойству `true` или `false`, в зависимости от нажатых кнопок формы. Если нужен возврат каких либо значений у формы делаете публичное поле, которое можно записать и которое можно прочитать.

```
public partial class DialogWnd : Window
{
    public DialogWnd()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    private void bOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Message = "OK!!!";

        DialogResult = true;
    }

    private void bCancel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Message = "Not OK :(";

        DialogResult = false;
    }
}
```